# Show dialog whilst table.ajax.url is loading in DataTables

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am using table.ajax.url to load a new URL upon certain conditions in my page.

This all works - however there is no obvious feedback that the data is loading or has loaded.

```
processing: true,
'language':{ 
    "loadingRecords": "Loading ...",
    "processing": "Loading ..."
},
```

This makes the "loading" message appear but it blends into the table to the extent that it's not noticeable.

Is it possible to trigger a bootstrap dialog when it's run and close when it's finished... or anything similar?

Comment: You can make use of `preXhr` and `xhr` events.
Have a look here : https://datatables.net/reference/event/preXhr and here : https://datatables.net/reference/event/xhr

Comment: How would one go about utilising this when using table.ajax.url with a new URL?